# How to get filepath in Python using the filename?

Tags: python, html, filenames, filepath

I know the name of the file stored on my pc which I want to open in a web page application. I need the to send the filepath to a html file for the same. So I want to get filepath using the filename in Python or HTML.

I tried using the os.path.dirname(filename) in Python but it didn't work because the attribute is supposed to be a path for this function.

Comment: unclear what you are asking or what you tried

Comment: So... Do you want a script to magically find a full path using only filename? Or are you in the directory with that file but can't get the full filepath?

Comment: use python to write script which will check all filename in all folders. You can use `for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/"):` for this.

Comment: on Linux is program `locate filename` which use database to keep "path/name" of all files and you can very fast find all files with this name (mostly there are more than one paht with this name)` You can use SQLite in Python to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use `os.path.abspath` to get a normalized absolutized version of the pathname
- use `os.walk` to get it's location

code :

```
import os
file_ = 'filename.txt'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/'):
    for name in files:
        if file_ in name:
            print (os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, name)))
```

output:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\filename.txt
```

Comment: I can see that it's slowing down the execution